# Running a test with a toy Spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

How do I make sure my test runs with a specific set of beans so that the test doesn't even attempt to load the actual context? Suppose I want to test some decorated Mapstruct mapper

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@DecoratedWith(CardMapperDecorator.class)
public interface CardMapper {
    // mapping methods
}
```

```java
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class CardMapperDecorator implements CardMapper {
    @Autowired
    private CardMapper delegate;

    public CardMapperDecorator(CardMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
// decorator logic
}
```

That test only needs that mapper (and I need it to be injected by Spring, don't ask), how do I do that? `@TestConfiguration` doesn't stop Spring from attempting to load the main context, `@TestConfiguration` beans simply have priority to "real beans". How do I make and pass a context that contains only that mapper (plus some plumbing beans Spring may need)? This is what I want:

```java
// some annotations, I guess, but nothing that will bootstrap the entire context
class CardMapperTest {
    @Autowired
    CardMapper cardMapper;
    // test logic
}
```

I hoped this would work, but it doesn't

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = CardMapperTestConfig.class)
class CardMapperTest {
```

```java
// in the same test package as CardMapperTest
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "src/main/java/com/example/somepackage/mapper") // can't reach to the src directory where my mappers are from the test root
public class CardMapperTestConfig {
}
```

Besides, it would load every bean from that package which may be acceptable, but not perfect

I also saw you could give your Spring Boot test a `@TestConfiguration` and use `@SpringBootConfiguration` as a stopper, but it doesn't seem to be the best solution (more of a fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you replace slashes with dots

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) // if you need Mockito annotations
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MapperConfig.class)
public class DetailsMapperTest {
    // ...
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "by.afinny.credit.mapper") // assuming this src package contains the mappers you need, including generated ones
public class MapperConfig {
}
```